# Expression Engine RSS Feed PubDate doesnt validate

Tags: validation, rss

I'm running out of ideas, could you please tell me what am I doing wrong? When trying to validate my rss feed I get the error that pubDate is in incorrect format. Even though it looks the same as advised in specs (well to me at this stage). Can you spot the error?

```
{preload_replace:master_channel_name="blog_post"}
{exp:rss:feed channel="{master_channel_name}" debug="yes"}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="{encoding}"?>
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
    xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">

    <channel>
    <atom:link href="http://www.yourpeakstate.com" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <atom:link href='http://pubsubhubbub.superfeedr.com/' rel='hub' />
    <title><![CDATA[{channel_name}]]></title>
    <link>{site_url}</link>
    <description>{channel_description}</description>
    <dc:language>{channel_language}</dc:language>
    <dc:creator>{email}</dc:creator>
    <dc:rights>Copyright {gmt_date format="%Y"}</dc:rights>
    <admin:generatorAgent rdf:resource="http://expressionengine.com/" />

{exp:channel:entries channel="blog_post" limit="10" dynamic_start="on" disable="member_data"}
     <item>
       <title>{exp:xml_encode}{title}{/exp:xml_encode}</title>
       <link>{page_url}</link>
       <dc:creator>{author_name}</dc:creator>
       <pubDate> {gmt_entry_date format="%D, %j %M %Y %H:%i:%s %Q"} </pubDate> 
       <guid>{page_url}#When:{gmt_entry_date format="%H:%i:%sZ"}</guid>
       <description><![CDATA[<img src="{main_post_image}" alt="{post_title} - Your Peak State"> {blog_content_1} {blog_content_2}]]></description> 
       <dc:subject>{exp:xml_encode}{categories backspace="1"}{category_name}, {/categories}{/exp:xml_encode}</dc:subject>
     </item>
{/exp:channel:entries} 

    </channel>
</rss>

{/exp:rss:feed}
```

Here is validation error: https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.yourpeakstate.com%2Frss%2Farticle-feed

I might be blind though as I've been looking at this for the past 2 hours...

It Tells me this should be the output:

```
<pubDate>Wed, 02 Oct 2002 08:00:00 EST</pubDate>
<pubDate>Wed, 02 Oct 2002 13:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
<pubDate>Wed, 02 Oct 2002 15:00:00 +0200</pubDate>
```

But this is the output I get:

```
<pubDate>Thu, 06 Aug 2015 17:50:00 +00:00</pubDate>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured out what is the problem. This is the correct, pubDate format incase someone else encounters this problem in the future...

```
<pubDate> {gmt_entry_date format="%r"} </pubDate>
```

I spent 2 hours for simple thing like this... Might save someone else the time in the future.. You're Welcome